# Offset of a given timezone from GMT in linux shell script

Tags: linux, timezone, offset

Is there a way to get the offset of a given timezone (identifier like EDT or America/New_York) from GMT in linux shell script?

Comment: What exactly are you "given"?

Comment: The string identifier for a timezone. e.g. America/New_York or EDT.

Comment: if you want to calculate from localtime its possible.  But from a non standard string that seems a little challenging.

Comment: The strings are under my control. So I can pass whatever string is required to the script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Export your TZ environment variable and print date with %z for timezone offset.

```
#!/bin/sh
export TZ=":Pacific/Auckland"
date +%z
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to mangle the current environment: `TZ=":Pacific/Auckland" date +%z`

Comment: We don't need a colon before timezone

Comment: Will this take into account daylight savings?

Comment: This just gives the time offset from UTC. If you are in timezone America/New_York like me this will yield -5 on winter and -4 on summer

Answer (score 4):

This is a roundabout way to do it but it works ([loosely based on this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/56451-days-difference-between-two-dates.html)):

```
#!/bin/bash
ZONE=$1
TIME=$(date +%s --utc -d "12:00:00 $ZONE")
UTC_TIME=$(date +%s --utc -d "12:00:00")
((DIFF=UTC_TIME-TIME))
echo - | awk -v SECS=$DIFF '{printf "%d",SECS/(60*60)}'
```

Save that as `tzoffset`, make it executable, and run it like this:

```
tzoffset PST
```

This script in its current form only handles abbreviated timezones.